# SQLAlchemy: Relation table with composite primary key

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-key-relationship

I have a set of tables that look like:

```
workflows = Table('workflows', Base.metadata,
                  Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                 )

actions = Table('actions', Base.metadata,
                Column('name', String, primary_key=True),
                Column('workflow_id', Integer, ForeignKey(workflows.c.id), primary_key=True),
               )

action_dependencies = Table('action_dependencies', Base.metadata,
                            Column('workflow_id', Integer, ForeignKey(workflows.c.id), primary_key=True),
                            Column('parent_action', String, ForeignKey(actions.c.name), primary_key=True),
                            Column('child_action', String, ForeignKey(actions.c.name), primary_key=True),
                           )
```

My ORM classes look like:

```
class Workflow(Base):
    __table__ = workflows

    actions = relationship("Action", order_by="Action.name", backref="workflow")


class Action(Base):
    __table__ = actions

    children = relationship("Action",
                            secondary=action_dependencies,
                            primaryjoin=actions.c.name == action_dependencies.c.parent_action,
                            secondaryjoin=actions.c.name == action_dependencies.c.child_action,
                            backref="parents"
                           )
```

So in my system, each action is uniquely identified by a combination of a workflow id and its name. I'd like each action to have `parents` and `children` attribute that refers its parent and child actions. Each action can have multiple parents and children.

The problem occurs when I have a function such as :

```
def set_parents(session, workflow_id, action_name, parents):
    action = session.query(db.Action).filter(db.Action.workflow_id == workflow.id).filter(db.Action.name == action_name).one()

    for parent_name in parents:
        parent = session.query(db.Action).filter(db.Action.workflow_id == workflow.id).filter(db.Action.name == parent_name).one()
        action.parents.append(parent)

    session.commit()
```

I get an error like:

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) action_dependencies.workflow_id may not be NULL u'INSERT INTO action_dependencies (parent_action, child_action) VALUES (?, ?)' (u'directory_creator', u'packing')
```

How do I get the relationship to set the workflow_id correctly?

Comment: Why do you need to have `workflow_id` in the `action_dependencies` table?

Comment: Because the primary key for an action is a composite of its name and workflow_id. If the workflow_id was not in action_dependencies, there'd be no way to tell which workflow's actions the dependency was referring to.

Comment: Good point, good point. let me think...

Comment: Please note that your `parents/children` relationships should also include the `workflow_id` in the `primaryjoin` and `secondary` conditions, or else you will get these for all worklows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See below working code. The key points are those I mentioned in the comments:

- proper composite `ForeignKey`s
- correct `relationship` configuration using the FKs

Code:

```
workflows = Table('workflows', Base.metadata,
                  Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                 )

actions = Table('actions', Base.metadata,
                Column('workflow_id', Integer, ForeignKey(workflows.c.id), primary_key=True),
                Column('name', String, primary_key=True),
               )

action_dependencies = Table('action_dependencies', Base.metadata,
                            Column('workflow_id', Integer, ForeignKey(workflows.c.id), primary_key=True),
                            Column('parent_action', String, ForeignKey(actions.c.name), primary_key=True),
                            Column('child_action', String, ForeignKey(actions.c.name), primary_key=True),
                            ForeignKeyConstraint(['workflow_id', 'parent_action'], ['actions.workflow_id', 'actions.name']),
                            ForeignKeyConstraint(['workflow_id', 'child_action'], ['actions.workflow_id', 'actions.name']),
                           )
class Workflow(Base):
    __table__ = workflows
    actions = relationship("Action", order_by="Action.name", backref="workflow")

class Action(Base):
    __table__ = actions
    children = relationship("Action",
                            secondary=action_dependencies,
                            primaryjoin=and_(actions.c.name == action_dependencies.c.parent_action,
                                actions.c.workflow_id == action_dependencies.c.workflow_id),
                            secondaryjoin=and_(actions.c.name == action_dependencies.c.child_action,
                                actions.c.workflow_id == action_dependencies.c.workflow_id),
                            backref="parents"
                           )

# create db schema
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# create entities
w_1 = Workflow()
w_2 = Workflow()
a_11 = Action(name="ac-11", workflow=w_1)
a_12 = Action(name="ac-12", workflow=w_1)
a_21 = Action(name="ac-21", workflow=w_2)
a_22 = Action(name="ac-22", workflow=w_2)
session.add(w_1)
session.add(w_2)
a_22.parents.append(a_21)
session.commit()
session.expunge_all()
print '-'*80

# helper functions
def get_workflow(id):
    return session.query(Workflow).get(id)
def get_action(name):
    return session.query(Action).filter_by(name=name).one()

# test another OK
a_11 = get_action("ac-11")
a_12 = get_action("ac-12")
a_11.children.append(a_12)
session.commit()
session.expunge_all()
print '-'*80

# test KO (THIS SHOULD FAIL VIOLATING FK-constraint)
a_11 = get_action("ac-11")
a_22 = get_action("ac-22")
a_11.children.append(a_22)
session.commit()
session.expunge_all()
print '-'*80
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's correct to have the primary key a foreign key. How does that work?

But to make composite constraint, a key that is "unique together", use this in the table definition:

```
UniqueConstraint(u"name", u"workflow_id"),
```

But if you really want it to be the primary key also you can use this:

```
PrimaryKeyConstraint(*columns, **kw)
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.PrimaryKeyConstraint

Comment: there's nothing wrong with foreign key constraints on primary keys; this is a typical way to get a 'one-to-one' relationship, to map subclasses to the database, or to have attributes that can all be "null together"