# Many to many relationship with a composite key on SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, composite-primary-key

Let's say I have the following model:

```
class Molecule(Base):
   db = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   data = Column(Integer)

class Atom(Base):
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   weight = Column(Integer)
```

And I want to establish a **many-to-many** relationship between Molecule and Atom, what would be the best way to do it? Notice that the **primary key** of Molecule is **composite**.

Thanks

Comment: Very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525797/sqlalchemy-relation-table-with-composite-primary-key

Comment: Oh, you're right, I hadn't seen that question (and I did search for it). Anyway I think my question and answer is way more concise so I'll keep them,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**many-to-many** association tables should be defined like this:

```
molecule2atom = Table(
  'molecule2atom',
  Base.metadata, 
  Column('molecule_db', Integer),
  Column('molecule_id', Integer),
  Column('atom_id', Integer, ForeignKey('atom.id')),
  ForeignKeyConstraint( 
    ('molecule_db', 'molecule_id'),
    ('molecule.db', 'molecule.id')  ),
)
```

And add the relatiohship to one of the models as usual, for example, in Class Atom add:

```
molecules = relationship("Molecule", secondary=molecule2atom, backref="atoms")
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked the solution given here better - [composite key many to many](https://avacariu.me/writing/2019/composite-foreign-keys-and-many-to-many-relationships-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Links can go dead - please copy + paste the important bits into your answer.

Comment: phew thanks for this. Looked through ~10 SO threads and none clearly explained the (I'm assuming very common) situation of establishing a many-to-many relationship where at least one table has a composite primary key. That article clearly explains the problem, a solution, common warnings, and common mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an association table or fully declared table metadata, you can use the `primary_key=True` in both columns, as suggested [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/ormconfiguration.html).

Association table example:

```
employee_role = db.Table(
    "employee_role",
    db.Column("role_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("role.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("employee_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("agent.id"), primary_key=True),
)
```

Metadata example:

```
# this is using SQLAlchemy
class EmployeeRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee_role"

    role_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

# this is using Flask-SQLAlchemy with factory pattern, db gives you access to all SQLAlchemy stuff
class EmployeeRole(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "employee_role"

    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Alembic migration for it:

```
op.create_table(
        'employee_role',
        sa.Column('role_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('employee_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('role_id', 'employee_id')
    )
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE agent_role (
    role_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    employee_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (role_id, employee_id)
);
```

In terms of relationship, declare it on one side (this should give you `role.employees` or `employee.roles` which should return a `list`):

```
# this is using Flask-SQLAlchemy with factory pattern, db gives you access to all SQLAlchemy stuff
class Employee(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    roles = db.relationship("Role", secondary=employee_role, backref="employee")
```

Your Role class can be:

```
# this is using Flask-SQLAlchemy with factory pattern, db gives you access to all SQLAlchemy stuff
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "role"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False, unique=True)
```