# SQLAlchemy: How to describe a many to many relationship with a bidirectional association object and composite foreign key?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to define a Many-to-Many Relationship with an Association Object like it's described in the [SQLAlchemy Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html?highlight=many%20many#association-object). Additionally, my `Project` model uses a composite primary key.

I also referred to the various answers at [another Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254600/many-to-many-relationship-with-a-composite-key-on-sqlalchemy) and came up with this minimal example:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    user_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    subscriptions = relationship(
        "Subscription", back_populates="user"
    )

class Subscription(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subscription"
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['project_id', 'repo'],
            ['project.project_id', 'project.repo'],
        ),
    )
    user_id = Column(ForeignKey("user.user_id"), primary_key=True)
    project_id = Column(ForeignKey("project.project_id"), primary_key=True)
    repo = Column(ForeignKey("project.repo"), primary_key=True)
    extra = Column(String(50))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="subscriptions")
    project = relationship("Project", back_populates="subscribers", foreign_keys="[User.user_id, Project.project_id, Project.repo]")


class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    project_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    repo = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    subscribers = relationship(
        "Subscription", back_populates="project"
    )
```

However it gives me a `NoForeignKeysError` at the `Subscription.project` relationship. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `foreign_keys=` for the `project` relationship is a (scalar) string that looks like a list. Does it work any better if you use a list of strings? i.e., `foreign_keys=["foo", "bar", …]`

Comment: Unfortunately not really. Now i get this: `Column expression expected for argument 'foreign_keys'; got 'Project.project_id'`

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/AJWszEyz) seems to make the errors go away, at least.

Comment: Great, that seems to work. Makes sense somehow to create the back reference of the primary keys in the Project table also.