# How Can I Build a ForeignKey to a Table Which Has Composite Primary Key?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to properly build my ForeignKey column for a table I'm defining. I've outlined my models here (and put a comment next to the problematic line in my PhoneNumber model):

```
class AreaCode(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'areacodes'
    area_code = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    exchanges = db.relationship('Exchanges', backref='area_code')


class Exchange(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'exchanges'
    exchange = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    area_code_pk = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('areacodes.area_code'), primary_key=True)


class PhoneNumber(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'phonenumbers'
    phone_number = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=4, scale=0), primary_key=True)
    exchange_pk = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('exchanges.exchange'), primary_key=True) # this doesnt work since Exchange has two primary keys
```

Here's what's happening:

My Exchange table has a composite primary key. This is required for my use case.

The PhoneNumber table I'm trying to define needs a ForeignKey to the Exchange table, but since the Exchange table has a composite primary key, I can't figure out how to make the relationship work.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In your example, Exchange only has one primary key? Should the `exchange` column also be `primary=True`?

Comment: Couple of things worth looking at: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.PrimaryKeyConstraint
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525797/sqlalchemy-relation-table-with-composite-primary-key

Also, what database are you using?

Comment: Hi @shazow, you're right, I typo'ed there. Exchange has two primary keys. Also, I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "can't figure out how to make the relationship work"? What have you tried? Did you specify the `foreign_keys` in `Relationship`? Alternatively you can specify the `primaryjoin` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after speaking with several great people on the sqlalchemy mailing list, I finally got the above problem figured out. Below is the final version of my code which allows me to relate properly between the tables:

```
class AreaCode(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'areacodes'

    area_code = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Exchange(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'exchanges'

    exchange = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    area_code_pk = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('areacodes.area_code'),
                             primary_key=True)
    area_code = db.relationship('AreaCode', backref=db.backref('exchanges', lazy='dynamic'))


class PhoneNumber(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'phonenumbers'
    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['exchange_exchange', 'exchange_area_code_pk'],
            ['exchanges.exchange', 'exchanges.area_code_pk'],
        ),
    )

    phone_number = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    exchange_exchange = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    exchange_area_code_pk = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    exchange = db.relationship('Exchange', backref=db.backref('phone_numbers', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Comment: When you were chatting to the SQL Alchemy folk did they specify why you should setup a  foreign key constraint on the table and why you would not do this directly upon the two columns `exchange_exchange` and `exchange_area_code_pk` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, @Carel, this was code I wrote over ~7 years ago and I'm honestly not sure. I tried searching through my inbox but wasn't able to find the thread -- I suspect it was on another email provider I had before my current one that I no longer have access to. Sorry :(

Comment: Thank you for going to so much effort @rdeggas I really appreciate it. I went through the SQL Alchemy [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#defining-foreign-keys) again which states that this is the only way to setup a compound foreign key between two tables. There is also now an article that digs into this a little by [Andrei Vacariu](https://avacariu.me/writing/2019/composite-foreign-keys-and-many-to-many-relationships-in-sqlalchemy)